# Using JSP as a template Engine does not work with Spring Boot 2. Unable to figure out which folder is Spring looking into for the .jsp files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

Tried everything that I could grab from the numerous posts on StackOverflow. 
a) Use application.properties - does not work

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

b) Use SpringBootServletInitializer class - does not work.

c) Use /resources/static  or /resources/templates - Does not work.

d) Tried all the different suggestions of Maven dependencies - Do not work.

If a project entirely based on JSP's HAS to move to another template engine prescribed by Spring Boot then all the talk of loosely coupled loses its meaning.

Can someone please explain how Spring Boot intends to work with JSP's ?

Comment: JSP will only work with a WAR and has severe limitations (hence the suggestions to use a different templating engine) due to the use of embedded containers.

Comment: Tried using a WAR packaging, that did not help. Also I understand the limitations detailed out on                                                                     
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-structuring-your-code  .... but there should be a way to work through those limitations.

Comment: Its hard to say exactly what your issue is without seeing more of your configuration. You haven't actually given us information so much as general complaints. It might help if you created a small project with one simple page to work on before trying to integrate a larger project

Comment: As stated it will only work with a war, which you need to package and run (running from the IDE will mostly not work). They wouldn't be limitations if you could work around them, so no you cannot work around them.